# How to add publish Apps to app catalog

Tags: sharepoint-apps

Please help me to publish Apps for Sharepoint 2013 to app catalog.

I have visited  [enter link description here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161234.aspx). But When I add an app to catalog I must type Name, Title, Short Description, Icon URL ... So. How to publish Apps with all properties (Name, Title, Desc...) are type by config file.

Thanks
Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

When you publish apps to for SharePoint app catalog you are adding an app package (.app file) to the to a custom document library. The metadata fields you mentioned are not required for uploading the app and are all optional, so you can bypass entering that information and still publish apps to the catalog. When you want to add the app to the site you can see the tile and basic information available.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161234.aspx#AddApps